# Will underlying content (hidden by z-index until exposed by user action) be ignored by Google?

Tags: seo, css, hidden-text

In my web app the application itself will take up most of the screen estate (the pink layer in the below picture), while the about page (the blue layer) is hidden below it, thanks to `z-index`. If the user clicks the about button, the pink layer will slide up, uncovering the about page. Since the about page explains the content of the page, could this affect my SEO?

[image]

I have seen websites like Spotify animate seamlessly between pages that have different URLs - could that, in case what I am currently doing is absolutely inadvisable, represent a good solution? How would I possibly approach that design practice?

Comment: Hmm, I know for sure that they announce they mark content in dropdowns, tabs and other hidden containers waiting for event to be triggered as not available, but I am not concern about the overlapping containers I guess google bot isn't so complex to calculate if your window is hidden under another, but it is possible, that's a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Search engine bots evaluate HTML content, not CSS positioning. Whatever text you have inside your HTML elements is all that matters.

So one question is, is the about page filled in on this one at the same time or fetched later? If it's fetched from a different URL, /about, search engines can find that, too.

Comment: Search engines _will_ take into consideration CSS: if text and background share the same color, text will be ignored, for example (as it can't be seen by the human eye). I'm not a savvy on the matter, but I'm quite sure that it's not HTML alone to be evaluated.

Comment: The about page and the app page share the same URL (they're both the index) and downloaded (is that what you mean?) at the same time.

Comment: @Willege Yes. I ignored the cloaking techniques some people try and pull. And, yes, that's what I meant about the URL.