# Do HTML elements with the boolean attribute hidden get picked up by search engines?

Tags: seo, html, web-crawlers

I recently learned of the existence of the [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) attribute. It basically hides elements that are not relevant in the current state of the webpage (e.g., a user that is not logged in):

```
<p hidden>Welcome back!</p>
```

Will search engines ignore elements that have the boolean attribute `hidden` attached to them?

Comment: See also [Will underlying content (hidden by z-index until exposed by user action) be ignored by Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91738/will-underlying-content-hidden-by-z-index-until-exposed-by-user-action-be-igno) and [How bad is it to use display: none in CSS?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/how-bad-is-it-to-use-display-none-in-css)

Comment: Thanks for the suggested reading @StephenOstermiller, I reviewed both questions, and they don't seem relevant since this is not CSS, just HTML.

Comment: Interesting question.  Have you used GSC to see what it pulls back when it crawls your page?

Comment: I have not, I'll set it up and report my findings. Thanks for the suggestion @Trebor

Comment: I don't see why this would be seen as different to any other hidden content. Bear in mind that this can be overridden by the `display` CSS property (which can make this attribute a bit misleading).

Comment: When using accordeon in ecommerce product sheet, or Faq display, there is obviously an hidden css part in the page. I frequently ask for it not to be in display none while loading the dom then hidden after the standard google bot downloaded the html. But in increase the CLS in the new core web vitals so be aware of it

Alernatively: just check in google with a full phrase in the hidden part, you will see if google find it and have your dedicated answer to this question